# Sum of Matrix with type names

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So I want to sum 2 matrix with operator overloading but i get an error on m2 Matrix varible saying "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type"

```
template <class type>
class Matrix
{
public:
Matrix(type row, type column, type index);
Matrix<type> operator+(Matrix<type>* other);
type getrow();//not important
type getcolumn();
type** getMatrix();
private:
    type row;
    type column;
    type index;
    type** matrix;
};

template<class type>
Matrix<type> Matrix<type>::operator+(Matrix<type>* other)
{
    if(this->row==other->getrow()&&this->column==other->getcolumn())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->row; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < this->column; k++)
            {
                other->getMatrix()[i][k] += this->matrix[i][k];
            }
        }
    }
    return other;
}

int main()
{
    Matrix<int>* m1 = new Matrix<int>(1, 3, 1);//(row,column,index)
    Matrix<int>* m2 = new Matrix<int>(3, 3, 3);

    m1 = m1 + m2;//error on m2
}
```

How do i solve this thx for the help :)

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, always include the *full* and *complete* error output, copy-pasted as text.

Comment: It seems like `m1 = m1 + m2;` is an attempt to add *pointers to matrices*, rather than two matrix objects. That’s not going to work. You don’t need to use pointers or `new`at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the problem is quite simple to figure out even without the full error output (but in the future please include the full error output).

With `m1 + m2` you add two ***pointers***, not two `Matrix<int>` objects (`m1 + m2` is essentially equivalent to `&m1[m2]`).

Either don't use pointers and `new`:

```
Matrix<int> m1(1, 3, 1);//(row,column,index)
Matrix<int> m2(3, 3, 3);
```

Or dereference the pointers:

```
*m1 = *m1 + *m2;
```

Comment: *m1 = *m1 + *m2 worked Thanks and next time i will be careful to state the full error